# Difference between "attempt" and "try"

Tags: meaning, verbs

As far as I understand, both "attempt" and "try" **describe active measures towards achieving a goal**. Words like "aim", "seek" are listed as synonyms, but seem not to indicate **active measures**.

What is the difference between:

> I am *trying* to fix the car
>
> I *tried* to fix the car

and

> I am *attempting* to fix the car (sounds unnatural)
>
> I *attempted* to fix the car

Personally, I think that "attempt" indicates one shot quick look (attempted, but was too much effort) and "try" indicates prolonged efforts (done everything I could)

Comment: I see zero difference.  "Attempt" is a little more formal, fancy sounding. So you can sometimes use it that way, to sound a little more pretentious, in some cases. Other than that they are identical.  Actually "try" can sound more pathetic .. as in "oh, dear, I'll try my best but..."  If someone at work challenges you "Can you do THIS?" .. if you answer "Look .. I'll try.." that's about as good as saying "....but it may not happen."

Comment: Regarding your final sentence, most words have more than one meaning.  "Attempt" can be used to label one specific attempt; so what. That's not relevant in a discussion between how "I'll attempt to do it" and "I'll try to do it" differ.

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try" [or "attempt"] ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my ear (product declaration: British-born wrinkly), your theory is right, there is something pessimistic about "attempting". There is no attempting, Yoda should have said, only the doing or not doing. When Eliot, perhaps echoing the *Gita*, wrote, "For us there is only the trying; the rest is not our business", to my ear that suggests a sustained moral endeavour.

I agree with you also that "I am attempting to fix the car" sounds a bit off, perhaps because, as above, it suggests that you don't think much of your chances.

Other NS may differ in their perception of the nuances, though.

Comment: They use "attempt" in the Olympics when talking about sports... particularly ones involving the word "vault"... pole vaulting, gymnastics vault of both the male and female varieties... also events like ski jumping. You could hardly say that these are "pessimistic" usages, simply really quick ones. All of these events are very short bursts of work.

Comment: That might be because "try" doesn't work as a noun – outside of rugby. Your point about the quick bursts works anyway.

Comment: HI David.  You probably agree that "I'll try to do it ..." is deifnitely a weak formulation, and indeed often implies essentially "probably will not be able to."  (Whereas "Ok, I will actually attempt it right now!" is more upbeat.) I see no difference, really.  Both can be used in an upbeat or downbeat manner, in different ways.

Comment: @JoeBlow. No, to me it's the other way round, "I'll try" is more upbeat than "I shall attempt it". This issue seems very subjective: _de gustibus_ and all that.

Comment: This is the best answer. The two are synonyms, obviously. But any two synonyms also have different connotations. And I agree with David that *attempt* sometimes has the connotation of a *hail-mary* effort, i.e., one with somewhat less expectation of success than what the more neutral *try* would suggest.

Comment: +1 on attempt having the connotation of singular measure, try of sustained/multiple - "a number of attempts were made" vs "a number of tries were made" might be one context to support this.

Answer (score 1):

Any claimed difference between ***to try*** and ***to attempt*** based on *degree of effort, likelihood of success*, etc. is spurious. The main differences are...

> 1: [***try*** is about 20 times more common than **attempt**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20tried%20to%2CI%20attempted%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20tried%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20attempted%20to%3B%2Cc0), as that linked chart shows.
>
> 2: ***try*** has a greater range of "extended" meanings - you can *try/hear a court case, try/sample a delicacy*, for example.
>
> 3: Where the context involves *doing A in order to achieve B*, the "possibility of failure" may apply to either A or B. Consider...

3a: *I tried rebooting the computer*
 3b: *I tried to reboot the computer*
 3c: *I attempted rebooting the computer*
 3d: *I attempted to reboot the computer*

...where 3b and 3d both imply the speaker probably wasn't able to reboot. 3a would normally imply he *was* able to reboot (it just didn't have the desired effect of fixing the problem). Idiomatically, 3c is an unlikely utterance, and I wouldn't like to say which of the two possible meanings might apply.

Answer (score 0):

*Try* indicates motive in expectancy of a result. *Attempt* indicates motive without expectancy of a result. Also, if you're *trying*, then you are currently occupied as such. If you're *attempting*, then you may be planning because *attempt* is prefixed with **a(t)-**, so any place or time may be designated.

By using *attempt* in a sentence such as 'I attempted to fix the car', you disconcern with result, suggesting that you conceal a potential failure for any peculiar reason. Anyway, that is rather psychology than English.